# Как отключить повышение привилегий при запуске старых приложений под ограниченный пользователем Windows 10 1607?

Tags: windows-10

В обновлении Windows 10 1607 (Anniversary Update) одним из нововведений стал [автоматический запуск некоторых приложений в режиме совместимости](https://superuser.com/a/1116454/236432). При этом происходит запрос повышения привилегий. (Есть программы, которые нормально запускались под пользователем в 1511, но стали просить административного доступа в 1607)

Таким образом при запуске некоторого ПО под учётной записью пользователя без административных привилегий отображается окно UAC с запросом учётных данных администратора. Без учётных данных администратора компьютера пользователь такое ПО запустить не может.

У проблемы есть описанное решение с использованием настройки совместимости с настройкой RUNASINVOKER через [установку переменной](https://superuser.com/questions/171917/force-a-program-to-run-without-administrator-privileges-or-uac) или [правку реестра](http://forum.oszone.net/thread-145492.html)

Но оба решения устраняют проблему запуска конкретной программы из конкретного места (при первом придётся править ярлык или делать bat-ник, при втором в реестре указывается полный путь запуска).

Необходимо решение как сделать, чтобы все программы запускаемые любым ограниченным пользователем (на администраторов не должно распространяться) стартовали с RUNASINVOKER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам же и нашёл ответ:

Переменные окружения текущего пользователя хранятся в `HKCU\Environment`.

Переменные окружения профиля по-умолчанию - `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Environment`

Добраться до переменной каждого пользователя, имеющего профиль в системе:`HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Environment`

Достаточно перебрать все ветки реестра `HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Environment` и добавить ключ с именем `__COMPAT_LAYER` типа `REG_SZ` со значением `RunAsInvoker` где требуется (там где пользователь не администратор).